# not able to push rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am trying to push a code which I pulled from bitbucket.

I get the below error when I do `git push heroku master`.

> fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>     and the repository exists.

I have the access to repo. What's wrong.

Comment: `git help remote` to gain further understanding

Answer (score 6):

Have you executed `heroku git:remote -a yourapp`?

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: yes, I tried that. I get this 

` ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to `

Comment: try to pull from your heroku master first: `git pull heroku master`, then force push if you still have errors with pushing `git push heroku master -f`

Comment: you mean `heroku pull`, my code will change to the heroku code then ?

Comment: The error message says that your upstream repository has made commits that would be lost if you were to push. So if you do a "git pull", you will be able to merge, and then push again.

Comment: If you are the only one using the repo, you can just do a `git push -f` to force push the current commit regardless of its relationship to the upstream branch.

Comment: now I get something like this..

`remote: 
remote: ! Cedar-10 is deprecated. Please update to Cedar-14: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app.git'
`

Comment: When was the last time you updated the Heroku toolbelt on your system?

Comment: never did something like that I believe.
PS: I am not the owner of the heroku app. I have the access

Comment: didn't understand it. my app name is app

Comment: I assume you are using Cedar-10 which is outdated. You need to upgrade your existing app to Cedar-14 by following the steps on the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking in 2017 and beyond, simply doing `heroku create` solves the issue, then you can do the `git push heroku master` command.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5